# In a React Native project, why is the top-level directory referred to in imports as 'app'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to understand the imports in some React Native source code. In a file `questionnaire.actions.js`, which is located relative to the top-level directory, which is called `lucy-app`, here:

```
./src/containers/newUserOnboarding/questionnaire/questionnaire.actions.js
```

This JS file contains the following import:

```
import api from 'app/src/api';
```

From the context, it is clear that the top-level directory is being referred to as `'app'`, because it contains a subdirectory `src` containing an `api.js`:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── api.js
```

My question is: why is is the top-level directory know as `app`? Is this some kind of default name for a React Native project? (I've looked a bit in the general Javascript documentation, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import, but couldn't find a reason there).

**Update**

I've noticed that my `package.json` in the top-level directory contains the following:

```
{
    "name": "app",
```

This is apparently making the directory 'referrable' as `app`. But how is this being done? In case it is one of the dependencies doing this, here are the dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "analytics-react-native": "^1.2.0",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.5.0",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.1.10",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.22.x",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.x",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "raven-for-redux": "^1.3.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.53.3",
    "react-native-android-keyboard-adjust": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-code-push": "^5.3.2",
    "react-native-config": "^0.11.5",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-intercom": "^11.0.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.4.4",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-markdown-renderer": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-material-kit": "git://github.com/xinthink/react-native-material-kit#95b0980",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^0.2.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.0.6",
    "react-native-phone-input": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.6",
    "react-native-router-flux": "4.0.0-beta.27",
    "react-native-sentry": "^0.35.3",
    "react-native-smart-splash-screen": "^2.3.5",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^0.4.3",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.11",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.3.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^4.10.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1",
    "validator": "^10.2.0"
},
```

**Update 2**

I'll try to share a simplified version of my directory structure, as a `tree` command results in tens of thousands of lines. Here is an `ls` of the directory above `lucy-app`:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy2 kurtpeek$ ls
Dockerfile      change_db_owner.sh  latest.dump     lucy-web        staging_db_12_July.dump
Procfile        crontab         lucy-app        readme.md
```

Here is a partial tree of `lucy-app`:

```
└── src
    ├── actions.js
    ├── api.js
    ├── app.js
    ├── components
    │   ├── Headshot
    │   │   ├── Headshot.js
    │   │   ├── Headshot.styles.js
    │   │   └── __tests__
    │   │       ├── Headshot-test.js
    │   │       └── __snapshots__
    │   ├── InfoCard.js
    │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   ├── InfoCard-test.js
    │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   ├── backButtonView-test.js
    │   │   ├── markdownView-test.js
    │   │   ├── splash-test.js
    │   │   ├── text-test.js
    │   │   └── webViewModal-test.js
    │   ├── backButtonView.js
    │   ├── buttons
    │   │   ├── ImageButton.js
    │   │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   │   ├── backButton-test.js
    │   │   │   ├── button-test.js
    │   │   │   ├── imageButton-test.js
    │   │   │   ├── intercomButton-test.js
    │   │   │   └── textButton-test.js
    │   │   ├── backButton.js
    │   │   ├── button.js
    │   │   ├── button.styles.js
    │   │   ├── intercomButton.js
    │   │   └── textButton.js
    │   ├── guideDialog
    │   │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   │   └── guideDialog-test.js
    │   │   ├── guideDialog.js
    │   │   └── guideDialog.styles.js
    │   ├── initial
    │   │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   │   ├── initial-test.js
    │   │   │   └── initialHeader-test.js
    │   │   ├── initial.js
    │   │   ├── initial.styles.js
    │   │   └── initialHeader.js
    │   ├── inputs
    │   │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   │   ├── dropdownField-test.js
    │   │   │   ├── emailField-test.js
    │   │   │   ├── label-test.js
    │   │   │   ├── numberField-test.js
    │   │   │   ├── phoneField-test.js
    │   │   │   ├── textField-test.js
    │   │   │   └── wrapField-test.js
    │   │   ├── dropdownField.js
    │   │   ├── emailField.js
    │   │   ├── label.js
    │   │   ├── numberField.js
    │   │   ├── phoneField.js
    │   │   ├── textField.js
    │   │   ├── textField.styles.js
    │   │   └── wrapField.js
    │   ├── markdownView.js
    │   ├── splash.js
    │   ├── text.js
    │   ├── validationMessage
    │   │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   │   └── validationMessage-test.js
    │   │   ├── validationMessage.js
    │   │   └── validationMessage.styles.js
    │   └── webViewModal.js
    ├── containers
    │   ├── changePassword
    │   │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   │   ├── changePassword.reducer-test.js
    │   │   │   └── changePassword.ui-test.js
    │   │   ├── changePassword.actions.js
    │   │   ├── changePassword.container.js
    │   │   ├── changePassword.reducer.js
    │   │   ├── changePassword.styles.js
    │   │   └── changePassword.ui.js
    │   ├── forgotPassword
    │   │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   │   ├── forgotPassword.reducer-test.js
    │   │   │   └── forgotPassword.ui-test.js
    │   │   ├── forgotPassword.actions.js
    │   │   ├── forgotPassword.container.js
    │   │   ├── forgotPassword.reducer.js
    │   │   ├── forgotPassword.styles.js
    │   │   └── forgotPassword.ui.js
    │   ├── infoCards
    │   │   ├── HowToUse.js
    │   │   ├── MeetGuide.js
    │   │   └── __tests__
    │   │       ├── HowToUse-test.js
    │   │       ├── MeetGuide-test.js
    │   │       └── __snapshots__
    │   ├── login
    │   │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   │   ├── login.reducer-test.js
    │   │   │   └── login.ui-test.js
    │   │   ├── login.actions.js
    │   │   ├── login.container.js
    │   │   ├── login.reducer.js
    │   │   ├── login.selectors.js
    │   │   ├── login.styles.js
    │   │   └── login.ui.js
    │   ├── navigation
    │   │   ├── Drawer
    │   │   │   ├── Drawer.js
    │   │   │   ├── Drawer.styles.js
    │   │   │   └── __tests__
    │   │   │       ├── Drawer-test.js
    │   │   │       └── __snapshots__
    │   │   ├── GuideNavBar
    │   │   │   ├── GuideNavBar.container.js
    │   │   │   ├── GuideNavBar.styles.js
    │   │   │   ├── GuideNavBar.ui.js
    │   │   │   └── __tests__
    │   │   │       ├── GuideNavBar-test.js
    │   │   │       └── __snapshots__
    │   │   ├── components
    │   │   │   ├── BackButton.js
    │   │   │   ├── OpenDrawerButton.js
    │   │   │   ├── OptionsMenu.js
    │   │   │   ├── QuestionnaireMenu.js
    │   │   │   └── __tests__
    │   │   │       ├── BackButton-test.js
    │   │   │       ├── OpenDrawerButton-test.js
    │   │   │       ├── OptionsMenu-test.js
    │   │   │       ├── QuestionnaireMenu-test.js
    │   │   │       └── __snapshots__
    │   │   └── navigation.styles.js
    │   ├── newUserOnboarding
    │   │   ├── activate
    │   │   │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   │   │   ├── activate.ui-test.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── activationCode.ui-test.js
    │   │   │   │   └── email.ui-test.js
    │   │   │   ├── activate.actions.js
    │   │   │   ├── activate.container.js
    │   │   │   ├── activate.reducer.js
    │   │   │   ├── activate.styles.js
    │   │   │   ├── activate.ui.js
    │   │   │   ├── activationCode.ui.js
    │   │   │   └── email.ui.js
    │   │   ├── activateHelp
    │   │   │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   │   │   └── activateHelp.ui-test.js
    │   │   │   ├── activateHelp.styles.js
    │   │   │   └── activateHelp.ui.js
    │   │   ├── activateSuccess
    │   │   │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   │   │   └── activateSuccess.ui-test.js
    │   │   │   ├── activateSuccess.styles.js
    │   │   │   └── activateSuccess.ui.js
    │   │   ├── education
    │   │   │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   │   │   └── education.ui-test.js
    │   │   │   ├── education.styles.js
    │   │   │   └── education.ui.js
    │   │   ├── loading
    │   │   │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   │   │   └── loading.ui-test.js
    │   │   │   ├── loading.container.js
    │   │   │   ├── loading.styles.js
    │   │   │   └── loading.ui.js
    │   │   ├── newUserOnboarding.reducer.js
    │   │   ├── notificationPermissions
    │   │   │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   │   │   └── notificationPermissions.ui-test.js
    │   │   │   ├── notificationPermissions.container.js
    │   │   │   └── notificationPermissions.ui.js
    │   │   ├── questionnaire
    │   │   │   ├── addressForm
    │   │   │   │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   │   │   │   └── addressForm-test.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── addressForm.actions.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── addressForm.container.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── addressForm.styles.js
    │   │   │   │   └── addressForm.ui.js
    │   │   │   ├── components
    │   │   │   │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   │   │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   │   │   │   ├── questionnaireFooter-test.js
    │   │   │   │   │   ├── questionnaireHeader-test.js
    │   │   │   │   │   └── questionnaireMenu-test.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── questionnaireFooter.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── questionnaireHeader.js
    │   │   │   │   └── questionnaireMenu.js
    │   │   │   ├── questionnaire.actions.js
    │   │   │   ├── questionnaire.container.js
    │   │   │   ├── questionnaire.reducer.js
    │   │   │   ├── questionnaire.selectors.js
    │   │   │   ├── questionnaire.styles.js
    │   │   │   ├── questionnaire.ui.js
    │   │   │   └── questions
    │   │   │       ├── __tests__
    │   │   │       │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   │       │   ├── booleanQuestion-test.js
    │   │   │       │   ├── dateQuestion-test.js
    │   │   │       │   ├── multiSelectQuestion-test.js
    │   │   │       │   ├── questionWrapper-test.js
    │   │   │       │   ├── selectQuestion-test.js
    │   │   │       │   └── textQuestion-test.js
    │   │   │       ├── booleanQuestion.ui.js
    │   │   │       ├── dateQuestion.ui.js
    │   │   │       ├── multiSelectQuestion.ui.js
    │   │   │       ├── optionalMessage.ui.js
    │   │   │       ├── questionWrapper.ui.js
    │   │   │       ├── selectQuestion.ui.js
    │   │   │       └── textQuestion.ui.js
    │   │   ├── questionnaireIntro
    │   │   │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   │   │   └── questionnaireIntro.ui-test.js
    │   │   │   ├── questionnaireIntro.container.js
    │   │   │   ├── questionnaireIntro.styles.js
    │   │   │   └── questionnaireIntro.ui.js
    │   │   └── setAccount
    │   │       ├── __tests__
    │   │       │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │       │   ├── email.ui-test.js
    │   │       │   ├── password.ui-test.js
    │   │       │   └── setAccount.ui-test.js
    │   │       ├── email.ui.js
    │   │       ├── password.ui.js
    │   │       ├── setAccount.actions.js
    │   │       ├── setAccount.container.js
    │   │       ├── setAccount.reducer.js
    │   │       ├── setAccount.styles.js
    │   │       └── setAccount.ui.js
    │   ├── profile
    │   │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   │   ├── profile.reducer-test.js
    │   │   │   └── profile.ui-test.js
    │   │   ├── profile.actions.js
    │   │   ├── profile.constants.js
    │   │   ├── profile.container.js
    │   │   ├── profile.reducer.js
    │   │   ├── profile.styles.js
    │   │   ├── profile.ui.js
    │   │   ├── profileForm
    │   │   │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   │   │   └── profileForm-test.js
    │   │   │   ├── profileForm.container.js
    │   │   │   ├── profileForm.selectors.js
    │   │   │   ├── profileForm.styles.js
    │   │   │   └── profileForm.ui.js
    │   │   └── profileSaveButton
    │   │       ├── __tests__
    │   │       │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │       │   └── profileSaveButton-test.js
    │   │       └── profileSaveButton.js
    │   ├── session
    │   │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   │   ├── session-test.js
    │   │   │   └── session.reducer-test.js
    │   │   ├── components
    │   │   │   ├── SessionDescription.js
    │   │   │   ├── SessionFooter.js
    │   │   │   ├── SessionHeader.js
    │   │   │   ├── SessionTimesModal.js
    │   │   │   └── __tests__
    │   │   │       ├── SessionDescription-test.js
    │   │   │       ├── SessionFooter-test.js
    │   │   │       ├── SessionHeader-test.js
    │   │   │       ├── SessionTimesModal-test.js
    │   │   │       └── __snapshots__
    │   │   ├── session.actions.js
    │   │   ├── session.constants.js
    │   │   ├── session.container.js
    │   │   ├── session.reducer.js
    │   │   ├── session.selectors.js
    │   │   ├── session.styles.js
    │   │   └── session.ui.js
    │   └── timeline
    │       ├── __tests__
    │       │   ├── __snapshots__
    │       │   ├── fixtures
    │       │   │   └── timeline-fixture.js
    │       │   ├── timeline-test.js
    │       │   └── timeline.reducer-test.js
    │       ├── components
    │       │   ├── __tests__
    │       │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │       │   │   ├── checkIn-test.js
    │       │   │   └── feedback-test.js
    │       │   ├── checkIn.ui.js
    │       │   ├── feedback.styles.js
    │       │   └── feedback.ui.js
    │       ├── timeline.actions.js
    │       ├── timeline.container.js
    │       ├── timeline.reducer.js
    │       ├── timeline.styles.js
    │       └── timeline.ui.js
    ├── hocs
    │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   ├── __snapshots__
    │   │   └── withValidationMessage-test.js
    │   └── withValidationMessage.js
    ├── images
    ├── lib
    │   ├── __tests__
    │   │   └── lodashMixins-test.js
    │   ├── analytics.js
    │   ├── customMarkdownRules.js
    │   ├── inputValidations.js
    │   ├── lodashMixins.js
    │   ├── loggingHelpers.js
    │   ├── requestHelpers.js
    │   └── utils.js
    ├── reducers.js
    ├── router.js
    ├── scenes.js
    ├── store
    │   └── configureStore.js
    ├── styles
    │   ├── colors.js
    │   ├── common.js
    │   └── styles.js
    └── test-config
        ├── enzyme-config.js
        └── setup.js
```

Comment: Its an arbitrary name. Even having the top level `src` directly is arbitrary. There's nothing baked into the frameworks that require these things, but it is a common pattern that a lot of people use. I honestly just use this pattern now too because when I'm reading other code or other people are reading mine, its one less mental overhead item to worry about.

Comment: The directory is called `lucy-app`, not `app`, though. Where is this 'arbitrary name' set? I assume that if you wrote `import api from 'foobar/src/api';` it would not work...

Comment: I would need to see your entire directory structure to really answer the question about your specific application.

Comment: The `name` in `package.json` can be used as a node module "root"; that's just how it works. Although you'll need to inform ESLint about this so avoid IDE/CLI ESLint errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert [Dave Newton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438992/dave-newton)'s comment to an answer, the `name` in `package.json` can be used as an 'alias' for the root directory.

For example, following https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html I ran `create-react-native-app AwesomeProject`, and then added a `src/greeting.js` with a default export function:

```
export default function sayHello() {
    return "Hello, world!";
}
```

Then I changed line 2 of `package.json` from `"name": "Awesomeproject"` to `"name": "app"`:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.14.0",
    "jest-expo": "~27.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^27.0.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "~0.55.2"
  }
}
```

Now the directory structure looks like this:

[image]

In `App.js`, I import the `sayHello()` function from `app/src/greeting`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import sayHello from 'app/src/greeting';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{ sayHello() }</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I noticed that this works: the simulator displays "Hello, world!":

[image]

So in this case, the top-level directory can be referred to both as `AwesomeProject`, the actual name of the directory, and `app`, the `name` in `package.json`. I find it more intuitive to keep these the same (as is the default of `create-react-native-project`), but perhaps it had been changed in the project under consideration for brevity.

Comment: This is a nice example how we can use name field for package.json. Well done. I've learned this thanks to you. Also, you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

It is not default name for a React Native project but maybe just a convention or habit. There are different types of directory structure approaches you can stick to or you can use `create-react-native-app` from [React Community](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app) and examine how this tool creates the directory structure. Hint: There is no directory structure :) So, everything is totally up to you.

Of course this is just the basic structure, according to your needs (like actions, reducers directories for Redux if you will use, config, api, etc) you can organize your own directories.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question because in my case, there is no directory called `app` in my directory structure; there is, however, a `"name": "app"` field in my `package.json`. But how does this make that directory 'referrable' as `app`?

Comment: It does not refer anything actually, just a name here and it is not related with the dependencies as you thought and asked in your question update. There must be an `app` directory somewhere in the main directory if there is a working import. So, if you share the whole directory structure we can say some more.

Comment: After your update it is clear that there is no `app` directory so this import should be something like `../../../api`. But, if this is working maybe there is an extra configuration that lets a usage like that. honestly, I don't know anything about this.

Comment: According to the good example given in the other answer, I've learned that actually name field can be used as an alias for the project root. So my previous statement which is "does not refer anything" is wrong.